Moving SUM analytic function from PostgreSQL to Redshift with RANGE window frame clause
I have the following code in PostgreSQL, which I need to reproduce on Amazon Redshift:
select *
from
(   select distinct
      a.id
      , sum(case when a.is_batch_empty then 1 else 0 end) 
           over (partition by a.client_id order by a.id) as empty_count
    from my_temp_table a
) a
where a.id = 111

In Amazon Redshift, this code execution fails with the following error:

Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

So, on Redshift, I need to add ROWS BETWEEN section.
The problem is that I cannot find the formula which gives the same result as on PostgreSQL.
What I tried so far:

Without ORDER BY

With a frame ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

With a frame ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING


I have different result with every of these options, and no one of them matches the PostgreSQL solution.
So, what I have to do with this formula to get identical results on PostgreSQL and Redshift?

Please provide a reproducible example: sample/mock rows, what you expect on output vs what you get on output on each of these attempts in Postgres and in Redshift. You say the results are different, but it would be helpful to see if and how exactly they differ.

In PostgreSQL order by in window spec implies between unbounded preceding and current row frame clause. If you remove order by, the frame spans the whole partition. Quoting the doc:

With ORDER BY, this sets the frame to be all rows from the partition start up through the current row's last ORDER BY peer. Without ORDER BY, this means all rows of the partition are included in the window frame, since all rows become peers of the current row.

And that's mentioned right after what you were looking for:

The default framing option is RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING, which is the same as RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

Your second attempt was the closest, but note that the default is RANGE, not ROWS and I don't see RANGE in Redshift window function doc. If a.id isn't unique, the results will differ as demonstrated here.
You could try to emulate the RANGE frame clause behaviour with a correlated scalar subquery:
select distinct a.id,
       (select sum(case when t2.is_batch_empty then 1 else 0 end)
        from my_temp_table t2
        where a.client_id=t2.client_id
          and a.id>=t2.id)
from my_temp_table a


Yes, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW produces the same result on PostgreSQL. But Redshift says: "RANGE clause of window functions not yet implemented". Is there any workaround?

Are you absolutely sure ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW dodn't give matching results? Really, a reproducible example would go a long way. As to a workaround, you can usually express the same logic in scalar/lateral subqueries.

Yes, I sure. Currently, I cannot see how to give the reproducible example, because the source table has hundreds of thousands rows, and I cannot figure which rows cause the differences. When I add any filter in the inner query (e.g. WHERE id = 111)), this breaks the logic. I will try subqueries. Sorry, I cannot upvote your answer because I do not have enough reputation yet...

@VitaliiLevchenko I've reproduced the behaviour in my demo, updated the answer and included an example of emulating the range behaviour with a scalar subquery. It won't perform as efficiently as a proper window function, but I it should be logically the same, get the same results.

Just remove the "order by a.id" clause. It doesn't matter in which order you sum the values.

As I already wrote, I tried this, but the the result was not identical to what I see on PostgreSQL. Moreover, even when I remove ORDER BY on PostgreSQL, the result has some differences, i.e. even on the PostgreSQL the formula with ORDER BY produces different result that the formula without ORDER BY clause.

Interesting. Likely has to do with the order of operations wrt district and windows. Can you post a test case that shows the differences you are seeing?

Unfortunately, the source table has hundreds of thousands rows, and I cannot figure which rows cause the differences. When I add any filter in the inner query (e.g. WHERE id = 111)), this breaks everything.

In PostgreSQL order by in window spec implies between unbounded preceding and current row frame clause. If you remove order by, the frame spans the whole partition. From the doc: "With ORDER BY, this sets the frame to be all rows from the partition start up through the current row's last ORDER BY peer. Without ORDER BY, this means all rows of the partition are included in the window frame, since all rows become peers of the current row."

So this says that there is a frame clause that depends on the ordering of rows where all the data is the same - a.id = 111.  This is under defined and arbitrary unless there is only a single row with a.id = 111 for each value of client_id.

@BillWeiner The order of rows that weren't explicitly resolved into specific positions by a strict order by is arbitrary and undetermined - it will not depend on anything, if that's what you mean. If rows are equal when evaluated in the order by expression, they are in a peer group. In groups and range mode, the frame will pass all rows of the peer group(s) into the function. In rows mode, you get arbitrary, individual rows from the peer group, unless you specify how to further split them up with more order by expressions.

Yes that is what I mean.  The issue is that Redshift doesn’t work this way - the ordering of the “peers” with the same order by rank will be random and change the result of the SUM() window function when the unbounded preceding frame clause is used.
